# What : means in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

How construction
`process resize_to_limit: [400,400]` 
works?
is process is a function? Why : after resize_to_limit?
Why [400,400] after :?

Library: MiniMagic
https://rubygems.org/gems/mini_magick/versions/4.11.0

Does it function than how it has been invoked?
What feature of ruby is used here?

Comment: process is a method, `resize_to_limit:` is a parameter, `[400,400]` is the parameter value -- in this case an array

Comment: dbugger is right but let me rewrite it in a more obvious way. The same code could be written as `process(resize_to_limit: [400, 400])`. Process is a method (function) name, `()` can be omitted in most cases. `resize_to_limit` is a keyword argument. Hash (dict) has a simiar syntax in Ruby ie. `{ resize_to_limit: [400, 400] }` would be a hash with key `resize_to_limit` and value `[400, 400]`.

Comment: Hashes can also be written with hashrocket `=>`, this syntax is still used in some cases and in older code in general.

Answer (score 2):

You understand it correctly in your initial 2 lines `process` is the function or as we call it in Ruby a method.

`resize_to_limit: [400,400]` is a hash argument to the process method which are also called dictionaries in Python I believe if that's easier to understand. The colon `:` itself is a syntax used to separate the key and value pairs of a hash in ruby but you can also use the hash rocket `=>` syntax but colon is preferred in most cases except for integer keys.

With all this being said you can write that same line like this `process({ resize_to_limit: [400,400] })`

I hope this helps you understand it better and happy coding!

Comment: In recent Ruby versions, `resize_to_limit:` would be considered a [keyword argument](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments) and – depending on the method definition – calling it with a hash might need [conversion](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Hash+to+Keyword+Arguments+Conversion) via `**`.

Comment: @Stefan It's only a keyword argument it the method accepts those. If the method is defined without keyword arguments then `resize_to_limit: [400,400]` is still an implicit hash. Without knowing the definition of `process` you cannot know if it's a keyword argument or implicit hash.

Comment: @3limin4t0r it gets converted to a hash if the method takes positional arguments. But until then, it's a keyword argument and no hash gets created.